# Check if a string contains specific characters using VBS script

Tags: vbscript, contains, string-comparison

My script is doing the following point :

1. Retrieve all my selected folder files
2. Class them by date (From the recent one to the older)
3. Show them in a window

Here is my VBS Script (I retrieve it [here](http://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/source/37322-vbscript-liste-des-fichiers-d-un-repertoire-tries-par-date-de-modification-du-recent-au-ancien)):

```
    Option Explicit

    Const PathMDB   = "C:\Users\C8461789\Desktop\test_script" 

    MsgBox TriRepertoire,,"Enumération " & PathMDB
    '---lister les fichiers du répertoire ---
    Function TriRepertoire()
    Dim fso, fichier, fileItem
    Dim i, imax, z, valeur, cible, liste
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    imax = 0
    'début de l'énumération
    For Each fichier In fso.GetFolder(PathMDB).Files
    Set fileItem = fso.GetFile(fichier)

    imax = imax + 1
    ReDim Preserve Tableau(2, imax)
    Tableau(1, imax) = Fichier.Name
    Tableau(2, imax) = FileItem.DateLastModified

    '---trier les fichiers par ordre décroissant de création ---
    Do
    Valeur = 0
    For i = 1 To imax - 1
        If InStr(Tableau(1,i), "average", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            If CDate(Tableau(2, i)) < CDate(Tableau(2, i + 1)) Then
                For z = 1 To 2
                   Cible = Tableau(z, i)
                   Tableau(z, i) = Tableau(z, i + 1)
                   Tableau(z, i + 1) = Cible
                Next
                Valeur = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next 
    Loop While Valeur = 1
    Set fileItem = nothing
    Next

    'Affichage du résultat classé
    For i = 1 To imax
    'If IsNull(Tableau) Then
        liste = liste &vbTab& Tableau(1, i) &vbCr 
    'End If
    Next
    TriRepertoire = liste

    Set fso = nothing 
    End Function
```

In order to filter by name my retrieved files, I would like to add the following condition :

- For each file name, if it contains "average", add the file name to the table
- Else, do nothing

I tried to use

> If InStr(Tableau(1,i), "average", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

But it shows me this error :
[image]

Comment: Interestingly when I google [`vbscript "type incompatible" "string"`](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=vbscript%20%22type%20incompatible%22%20%22string%22&rct=j) the results returned all relate to French code implementations which makes me think it's something to do with a compatibility between the French language and WScript.

Comment: This looks to be a similar problem may help. [Topic: type incompatible: 'CDbl' 800A00D (line 75)](http://forum.forensit.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=371).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `InStr` incorrectly. Your code:

```
InStr(Tableau(1,i), "average", vbTextCompare)
```

The signature for `InStr` is:

```
InStr([start,]string1,string2[,compare])
```

But the gotcha here is that it has two optional parameters, one of them being in the front, with a special condition:

> Optional. Specifies the starting position for each search. The search begins at the first character position (1) by default. **This parameter is required if compare is specified**

So because you are using the fourth parameter with the value `vbTextCompare`, you need to specify the starting point in the first parameter as well, which would be `1` (first character) in your case. So, the corrected code is:

```
InStr(1, Tableau(1,i), "average", vbTextCompare)
```

The error message you see basically complains that the first parameter is expected to be an integer, but you are feeding it a string.

See [InStr docs](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_instr.asp).