# Input Box contains specific word

Tags: string, vbscript

How would I check if an input contains a certain character? For example if I have this:

```
word = inputbox("What time is it?")
```

How would I check to see if the input contains the number '7' for example? I've seen the `InStr Function` but I don't know who to use it for this. Is this the correct way to use it? I don't care about the  `vbCompare` part.

```
If Instr(word, "7") then
b=msgbox("OK", 0, "7")
wscript.quit
else 
c=msgbox("No 7", 0, "None")
end if
```

Comment: You would use it as you would check any string with `InStr()`. The `InputBox()` function returns a string, so yes this should work. Was that your question or do you get an error or unexpected result? Honestly though, the example code doesn't make much sense and could be better structured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string contains specific characters using VBS script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864189/check-if-a-string-contains-specific-characters-using-vbs-script)

Comment: Yes, I was just wondering how to use the function, but I understand now. It's just a piece of the code and I'm still working on it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this to check (Updated):

```
if  InStr(1, word, "7", vbTestCompare) then
msgbox "You typed something with 7 in it."

elseif not InStr(1, word, "7", vbTestCompare) then
msgbox "You did not type something with 7 in it."

end if
```

Comment: This only works if 7 is the only thing typed into the `InputBox`. I want to know if I type in 7:30 PM, is there a 7 in that.

Comment: Shows serious mis-understandings of boolean logic.

Comment: I'm confused on what the vbTestCompare does. I've looked on MSDN but still don't completely understand.